# How to achieve alignParentBottom="true" property in LinearLayout

Tags: android

If i want to set an image to the bottom of any screen then we can use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in relative layout. But because of some reason i am bound to use LinearLayout.  There are other views (button, image button, listview) in the screen also. I want to place image at the bottom of my screen. Whatever may be the situation user wil be able to see this imageview at the bottom of the screen. How to achieve `alignParentBottom="true"` property in LinearLayout. See the folowing sample xml. I am using example1.xml but i want look and file that of example2.xml

**example1.xml**

[image]

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="I am sunil" 
        android:gravity="bottom"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**example2.xml**

```
<

?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="I am sunil" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have both a gallery view and a listview, you could add weight to one of them, meaning that it would grow as much as possible. If you give a weight to more than one view, they will share the extra space proportionally.

For instance, add to your gallery and listview `android:layout_weight="1"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gravity="bottom"` for `LinearLayout`.

For more information about `Gravity` property [look here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html)

Here is sample code, Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="I am sunil" 
        android:gravity="bottom"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Use `gravity="bottom"` for `LinearLayout` instead of `TextView`.

Comment: I have used Gravity= "Bottom" but i did not get same effect as i am getting in alignParentBottom="true" in relativelayout

Comment: as i have mentioned in that layout there is not only one image. there is gallery view, listview also