# Align Relative Layout at bottom of Linear Layout in Parent

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I have Linear Layout which acts as the parent of a Relative layout.The Relative layout consists of some buttons and stuff.I want to align the relative layout(panel containing buttons) at the bottom of the linear layout.The linear layout only consists of an ImageView and after that the relative layout should be aligned at the bottom.

But when i try to set  `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in the Relative Layout the IDE Prompts code is wrong.How can i achieve this please help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/jellyfish" />

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="318dp"
        android:layout_height="164dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/backgrad"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
            android:onClick="clickme"
            android:text="Button" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
            android:onClick="textclick"
            android:src="@drawable/text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:onClick="wmark"
            android:text="Save" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: FWIW statements like "android:layout_width="318dp"" make me worry. You should make relative statements, not absolute statements, wherever possible. What is wrong with wrap_content here I do not know.

Comment: @SK9 Yeah,i will change it.Actually im worried about the UI display on larger devices like Tablets.There will be a lot of blank space below,so need to some how centralize the items

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to place a RelativeLayout at the bottom of a RelativeLayout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492721/how-to-place-a-relativelayout-at-the-bottom-of-a-relativelayout)

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate : [How to achieve alignParentBottom="true" property in LinearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579420/how-to-achieve-alignparentbottom-true-property-in-linearlayout)

When you set `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, you are trying to use methods of the LinearLayout. But LinearLayout DO NOT provide `alignParentBottom`.

The answer in the duplicate says to replace

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

by

```
android:gravity="bottom"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your parent linear layout xml:

```
android:gravity="bottom"
```

Comment: Did you try adding it to your parent linear layout though (which you've since added to the XML in your question)? And what is meant by didn't work? Hmm... I suspect this is not going to give you exactly what you want, because you probably want a different gravity for the image child view. That is, quite possibly you want the parent to be a RelativeLayout, but it's up to you.

Comment: I had added the full xml earlier but somehow it did not appear.The (bottom panel) relative layout is not aligned at bottom even after adding the code you provided in the relative layout

Comment: Again, did you try adding it to your parent linear layout? (Again, _not_ the relative layout.)

Comment: well what i want is to align the items in relative layout (with a different background) at the bottom.How will adding this to the parent fix this?

Comment: _Again_, did you _try_ adding it to your parent linear layout? Both answers to your question advise this, at the time of writing. It's the best you can do when your parent is a linear layout, and it must be set on the parent. You seem to be ignoring this advice and doing your own thing.

Comment: No i have not tried it yet.The thing is my work machine just got crashed again.Will get back after recovering it.Thanks

Comment: So did you ever try this?

Comment: It works but the ImageView is dragged below,i need it to stay on top without any gap

Comment: Yes. That's all LinearLayout can give you. Declaring `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:layout_height="0dp"` on your image view might suit you. Try it. Otherwise you'll have to replace the parent with a RelativeLayout. You're asking a lot of LinearLayout here.

Comment: well,i dont want to stick with Linear Layout.What im trying to create is a menu bar below, like one used in snapspeed,see this image http://www.droid-life.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Snapseed.png see the menu bar above with the logo and the image buttons.Like that but below

Answer (score 0):

I have answered another topic like this, solution is to put a View with weight 1 above your relative layout like this:

```
    <View android:id="@+id/emptySpace"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Enclosing your ImageView in a Linear Layout and add

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

in your Relative Layout.